# Correct way to create a Dockerfile for WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, docker, dockerfile

I have recently started looking into Docker and wanted to understand one thing:
If I want to create a Dockerfile for WordPress, I would need Apache and PHP. But when I see the source Dockerfile for Apache and PHP, I see they are already including a Linux in them.
My questions are:
- Do I still need to have a Linux included while Apache and PHP already have it?
- Will it create a conflict as Apache and PHP already have a Linux environment?

Comment: You must install WordPress in a container with PHP. Containers work isolated and do not conflict

Comment: Thanks. Can you point to a link where I can read more about this? I know about containers but not sure how to install WordPress within a Container. Do you mean I run a PHP container and while it is running, run commands to install WordPress? If yes, how can I make a Dockerfile if I need that for distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux is an operating system. This is the starting point for the Dockerfile.

Linux isn't part Apache or PHP, that's PHP and Apache that are installed on top of it.

To give you a equivalent, it's like saying that WAMP includes windows.

So this is natural for your Dockerfile to build on an already existing image of an operating system, here Linux, and then install Apache, PHP and finally wordpress.

Making your own Dockerfile is a good idea to learn, but keep in mind that a lot of images already exist on Docker hub, including for wordpress : [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Does this mean that if I want to create a Dockerfile for WordPress, I would have to build it on top of an OS like Linux and in addition to that, I would have to put raw PHP, Apache libraries and not an image pulled from docker hub?

Comment: You cannot merge docker images, so you have to start with an existing image from docker hub and do things with it, then you'll an enhanced image.
You can chose to start from 'scratch' - a linux distribution -, to start from a XAMP - Apache/PHP/Mysql on top of a linux distribution - or to start directly from a wordpress installation out of the box

Comment: I suggest you to follow [docker guide](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/#containers-and-virtual-machines) to better understand the logic, then it'll come naturally to you.